# multiprocessing.Pool.map() method is throwing AttributeError

Tags: python, dataframe, multiprocessing

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

class A:
  def __init__(self, n):
    self.n = n

  def __foo(self, i):
    return i + 1

  def bar(self):
    l = list(map(self.__foo, range(self.n)))
    print(len(l))

  def baz(self):
    pool = Pool(2)
    l = list(pool.map(self.__foo, range(self.n)))
    print(len(l))

a = A(3)
a.bar()
a.baz()
```

Here is the brief output:

```
3
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute '__foo'
```

I want use `Pool` to process a big `dataframe`, but `Pool.map` doesn't work — how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a double-underscore name for `__foo`; the name gets mangled.

Use `_foo` if you want to mark a member internal or "private".